# with mv, consider the path/name of the original file when choosing destination

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

Say I need to move the file `/etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/a.out` to `/etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/b.out`

Typing the whole path twice is tedious, and going to the directory might not be ideal. Is there a way to do such a move without retyping the directory?

On a related question (that I suspect has the same solution). Say I want to move a file `someverybigfilename.png` to `somereallybigfilename.png`. Is there a way to accomplish that without retyping the name?

(I know I can use a script. But does `mv` support some such thing natively?)

In short: how can I use move to partially alter/alter just a part of a filename? How to do a small change like extension?

Comment: Make a function in your bashrc file that takes 3 args, path, file1, and file2, and just build up paths to both files internally. Id post an answer but i am not able to do so on phone. I will later unless somebody does it before me

Comment: The first is simple - using brace expansion: `mv /etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/{a.out,b.out}` or even `mv /etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/{a,b}.out`

Comment: @steeldriver please post as an answer :)

Comment: @George done ... now that I figured out Pt 2 ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the first case, if you are using `bash`, you can use [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html):

```
mv /etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/{a.out,b.out}
```

or even

```
mv /etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/{a,b}.out
```

In the second case you could use brace expansion again:

```
mv some{very,really}bigfilename.png
```

Or (although it doesn't really save much typing) you could use Bash [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) as follows:

```
$ mv someverybigfilename.png !#$:s/very/really
mv someverybigfilename.png somereallybigfilename.png
```

Comment: mv some{very,really}bigfilename.png seems to work as well

Comment: @josinalvo good point

Comment: Fascinating. Can you recommend link to read up on braces and where/how they are typically used for substitutions?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix: See the links I added in my edit.

Answer (score 2):

either

```
cd /etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/
mv a.out b.out
```

or

make a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_Path="/etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/"

mv $dir_Path\a.out $dir_Path\b.out

exit
```

and to rename:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_Path="/etc/dir1/dir2/dir3/"
name_part="bigfile.png"
cd $dir_Path
mv some$name_part somereally$name_part

exit
```

Answer (score 2):

If the path is the same I don't see the reason why not entering in the folder.

You could save the path with pushd or came back with cd -

Example:

```
luca@elite:~$ pushd dir1/dir2/dir3/
~/tmp/dir1/dir2/dir3 ~/tmp
luca@elite:~/dir1/dir2/dir3$ mv a.out b.out
luca@elite:~/dir1/dir2/dir3$ popd
~/tmp
luca@elite:~$
```

or

```
luca@elite:~$ cd dir1/dir2/dir3/
luca@elite:~/dir1/dir2/dir3$ mv b.out a.out
luca@elite:~/dir1/dir2/dir3$ cd -
luca@elite:~$
```

About the filename the only thing that came to my mind is to store it in a variable..

Answer (score 1):

There's several ways to approach this. One could be via function defined in `~/.bashrc` file.

```
pmv(){
    mv "$1"/"$2" "$1"/"$3"
}
```

The `pmv` function then would take 3 arguments. Path to directory, source file, and destination file. For instance:

```
$ ls testdir
self_test.sh*  test.wxg
$ pmv ./testdir  test.wxg  test2.wxg                                                                                     
$ ls testdir                                                                                                             
self_test.sh*  test2.wx
```

Notice that in this function we join directory path and file path with slash, thus when path to directory is given as command-line argument, there shouldn't be a trailing slash at the end. We can, however, improve the function definition using bash's [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), which will then allow us to use either `/path/to/dir` or `/path/to/dir/`:

```
pmv(){
    mv "${1%/}"/"$2" "${1%/}"/"$3"
}
```

---

> On a related question (that I suspect has the same solution). Say I want to move a file someverybigfilename.png to somereallybigfilename.png. Is there a way to accomplish that without retyping the name?

Effectively,no, there is no way to do that with `mv` alone. Even steeldriver's and mine solutions for first part of your question make use of `bash`'s features, not `mv`'s. More advanced renaming manipulations, such as in your case inserting text into filename, should be done with `prename` where you use perl regular expressions to dynamically rename files.

```
$ touch someverybigfilename.png

$ prename 's/very/really/' someverybigfilename.png                                                                       

$ ls somereallybigfilename.png                                                                                           
somereallybigfilename.png
```